# Thinkin sphinx facets on has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a model Foo which has many Bars and i am trying to define a facet so that when i list all the Foos i can have links with the foo_name and the count of its Bars :  . Is it possible in a rails 3 application ?

Thanks

Comment: did you have a chance to try the examples from [here](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/facets.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using counter cache column (see Railscast #23) it shouldn't be a problem.